SMT Component Identitfication, Two Output Clocks: 32 kHz and 8 MHz
I need to identify an SMT component on a PCB I buy used, which is circled in the attached photo.
I have been able to determine that it provides two clock frequencies. An early design (subsequently modified, but unfortunately I don't have the final design details) was showing two separate resonators connected to the same pins of the microcontroller (PIC18F87J10): one at 32 kHz; the other at 8 MHz. Browsing an online catalog (DigiKey) I haven't been able to find anything that resembles what I have. The top of the component has the characters 799 M, and a later design update has 799 P (which coincided with an upgrade to the microcontroller PIC18F87K22). The component has 6 pins and at the base measures approximately 4.5 mm by 2 mm. What exactly are these two components 799M and 799P, and where can I find their specs please?


It looks like it's tied to the OSC1 and OSC2 pins of the PIC18, which makes sense given your findings. I've found a number of dual-output crystal or MEMS oscillators looking around, but I can't find any that match this package... this may be hard to identify. As you've probably already determined.

The marking and packaging style looks similar to the Murata Ceralock CST series.

It's probably a Murata CSTCR7M99 ceramic resonator. LCSC doesn't have a picture of this particular one, but here is one of the CSTCR7M37G55B-R0.

As far as I can tell when looking at the datasheet, the pinout of the resonator...

... is consistent with what is shown in the datasheet (page 31) of the PIC.


Thank you! One Murata document shows that the different letters following the number 799 are EIAJ codes, indicating year and month of manufacturing https://www.murata.com/en-us/support/faqs/timingdevice/ceralock/char/cch0005
